# Preferred method re-ordering csv files by row in Java

Tags: java, csv, iteration

Say for example you have a csv file with headers that are at the bottom of the file, as such:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d
```

You want to reorder it as such

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
```

I basically have two ways of doing this I was wondering which was more efficient in terms of memory usage. I suspect that the first one is the case but was wondering if there were different opinions.

First method:

- Iterate through the file, until we reach the last line, store this in a variable.
- Write variable to file
- Iterate through file again writing each line, except the last one.

Second method:

- Iterate through the file storing each line as an item in an arraylist
- write last item in arraylist to file
- iterate through arraylist writing each item to file except the last one.

I've always been taught to put things in memory (the second way) when you need to randomly access a variable in the dataset (It's the 'DOM' way) whereas if you are just reading/writing files to use the first way (The 'SAX' way in xml terms), I can't help thinking that having to iterate through the dataset twice (the first way) is really sloppy. Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: I would have suggested to just delete the last line in the file, and add the line to the existing file, but there is no easy way to do this from my quick google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of the file you might do it like this

```
static final Charset FILE_ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

List<String> inLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.csv"), FILE_ENCODING);
inLines.add(0, inLines.get(inLines.size()-1));
inLines.remove(inLines.size()-1);
Files.write(Paths.get("output.csv"), inLines, FILE_ENCODING);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read file from stream and write it to another stream. While doeing that remember to write the last line as the first line. Delete the original file and rename the copy as the original file.

To do this, you have to store all the first file content into a variable: a String, an ArrayList, or something like that.

If you want to append something to a file, just open it in *append mode*:

```
new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(PATH, true));
```

But it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Memory wise this would not have any improvement over the second approach as you would still have to store he contents of the file in memory. In this hypothetical scenario I have no idea what size the file is so would rather not risk storing it in memory.

Comment: If the resource you want to save is memory at the expense of cpu, read the file until the end and store each line always in the same string, overwriting it, in order to have the last line stored in this string. Now create a new file, write as first line the string previously saved. Then read again the first file and write each line (except the last) into the new file. Delete the original file and rename the copy as the original file.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using RandomAccessFile:
1. Seek to the end.
2. Read the header backwards (not directly supported, but can be done byte by byte).
3. Write the header to a new file.
4. Seek to the beginning of the original file (or open it again, with a FileReader).
5. Iterate through the file writing to the result file, except for the last line.

Not sure if it is faster, but could be.